# How to unblock blocked wget and aptitude?

Tags: linux, debian, firewall

My debian server's wget and aptitude was blocked by firewall administor. Which ports should I inform firewall to unblock?

Comment: My server and firewall are isolated hardwares. The firewall is securing the whole data center. My server is just one of computer there.

Answer (score 0):

`wget` supports HTTP, HTTPS, and FTP, so by default that's 80, 443, 20, and 21 (all TCP).

`apt` can use HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, RSH, and SSH, so that's 80, 443, 20, 21, 514, and 22 (also all TCP), though if all of the repositories listed in `/etc/apt/sources.list` are HTTP URIs (which they probably are), just 80 will do.